Conformally mapping between the upper half complex plane, and the plane with a tree on spatial points removed
A stochastic process such as SLE$_{\kappa}$ can be defined by taking the scaling limit of a curve in the upper half complex plane: put simply, one removes a line segment, then another, $n$ times, each time conformally mapping the upper half complex plane to the upper half complex plane with this curve removed. Directly from T. Kennedy's paper (J. Stat. Phys. 137, No. 5-6, 839-856, 2009, MR2570752,  Zbl 1192.60093):

This nice diagram from that paper is helpful in getting the idea of what happens when many of these maps are composed:

The scaling limit as $\rho \to 0$ then looks a bit like Brownian motion, but can be used to address many fundamental probabilistic objects using tools from complex analysis.
What I am thinking about: is it possible to do the same with a tree, rather than a non-intersecting curve? So one would define a spatial tree such as the Euclidean minimal spanning tree on a set of points in the upper half complex plane, in the same way. This might give some complex analysis tools access to studying Euclidean spanning trees, and by implication, networks.
From what I can see, one can think of applying Kruskal's algorithm (for finding the minimum spanning tree), but where the algorithmic process would now be applying a composition of conformal maps (as one can do to produce an SLE trace numerically), rather than just selecting edges of the complete graph iteratively.
Is this possible? Does anything rule out such a sequence of maps that would allow me to draw a tree in the diagram above, rather than a simple curve?
My understanding is that the Riemann mapping theorem is sufficient to demonstrate this.

"conformally mapping the complex plane to the complex plane with this curve removed". Complex plane cannot be mapped conformally on anything else but itself. You probably mean the half-plane. A half-plane can be mapped conformally onto any simply connected region, other than the plane, by the Riemann mapping theorem.

I think QLE may be very close to what you have in mind...

Very helpful, thank you, that looks promising, I saw a few papers on Laplacian growth process while looking around but didn't see the link to QLE.

@Eremenko thank you very much, its quite simple then. One just needs a simply connected region, and then map the half plane to it (unique or otherwise), and it will be conformal.

"Quantum Loewner Evolution" https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5745

Is it possible a heuristic explanation can be given of things like DLA and QLE, involving the link to holomorphic dynamics? These papers can be a bit impenetrable if one is trying to simulate these things on a computer (hence the motivation for Kennedy's paper), but still the link is very useful.
